# What is/are legitimate use-cases of a static event in C#?

Tags: c#, events, static

We stumbled upon a codebase which is using static events. Static events have many problems I read everywhere. Information on *why not* to use static events is plentiful. As such, we replaced them by better alternatives, making our codebase more robust.

What is a *legitimate* usecase of static events?

Comment: Well, when you have a static source of information?

Answer (score 2):

*A* legitimate usecase would be if the calling method was static.
In `ASP.NET` WebMethods are required to be static, and therefore all other method calls must exist from an object instantiated exclusively in that method, or be static.

Or perhaps the source of information being provided to the even was static. as stated by Stefan.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility that comes to  mind is something like an unhandled exception handler. That catches unhandled exceptions within your application.